# Windows ExecuteSearch not returning all the users in a group

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory

In our application we are using the Windows executesearch API to find all the users in a group. However, I am finding that from my application, the executesearch API is returning only a subset of the users in the group. My procedure is the usual one, connect to the server with ADsOpenObject, instantiate an IDirectorySearch and invoke its ExecuteSearch method, then use GetFirstRow and GetNextRow to iterate. However, when I ran the same method and same arguments as a standalone program in C++, I see that the ExecuteSearch is working fine and returning all the users in the group. Any idea why this is not working from my application even though same arguments are passed? Is their any way we can debug or trace the call to executesearch? Will the windows event logs print anything if ExecuteSearch fails for all users or any external windows tools can be used to debug this ? Any help on how to debug this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess: Non initialized variables/structures. Did you get the same results (wrong behavior) in a debug too version, or only in release version?

Comment: Both versions, release and debug yielded the same results. Is their any way to debug the ExecuteSearch API calls, I tried to use DebugView which comes as part of SysInternals but it did-not print anything. I also looked at the Windows event logs to find why ExecuteSearch was not returning all the users but even that did-not give any useful data.